# Rethinkdb pattern for dynamic pubsubs through socketio

Tags: meteor, socket.io, rethinkdb

Coming from the Meteor world & I'm curious how to replicate the cached pubsub/observers functionality. For a basic example, let's say I have a todolist where each todo has a `userId` and I want to keep todos private to each `userId` (but a `userId` could exist on multiple connected devices, eg phone + desktop). I imagine I have to create some publish function that verifies the `userId` by the `socketId` from the sent request, then create a socket namespace specific to that query (since the query could include more than a `userId` constraint). Then, register an emitter that only sends the changes to those `socketId`s that are verified to listen to the given namespace. Am I close? All my research just returns basic things like publishing to all connected users based on keywords. Any links to reading material would be great! Here's a first attempt with the missing logic in comments...

```
export function sendTodosByUserId(io, userId) {
  //How to auth? By linking a client socketId to a user in a lookup table?
  connect()
    .then(conn => {
      r
        .table('todos')
        .filter(todos => todos("userId").eq(userId))
        .changes().run(conn, (err, cursor) => {
        cursor.each((err, change) => {
          //Do I emit a unique message? namespace?  How do I handle 2 clients using the same userId?
          io.emit('TODO_CHANGE', change);
        });
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some way of mapping new sockets to the correct user. For example, you could put the `userId` in a [Express session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) and store the user's socket ids in a simple object.

```
var userSockets = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   var userId = socket.handshake.session.userId;
   if(userSockets[userId]) {
     userSockets[userId].push(socket.id);
   } else {
     userSockets[userId] = [socket.id];
     sendTodosByUserId(io, userId)
   }

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      var i = userSockets[userId].indexOf(socket.id);
      userSockets[userId].splice(i);
      if(userSockets[userId].length === 0) {
        delete userSockets[userId];
      }
   });
});
```

In your `sendTodosByUsedId`, you would just loop over the socket array belonging to the user, and emit to every socket.

```
var sockets = userSockets[userId];
for(var i = 0; i < sockets.length; ++i) {
  io.to(sockets[i]).emit('TODO_CHANGE', change);
}
```

Note that this *will **not** work* if you have multiple nodes the user can be connected to. Then you might have to store the `userSockets`-object in e.g. Redis.

Alternatively, you could just have your users join a room named e.g. `user:<userId>`, and emit to this on every todo-change.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   var userId = socket.handshake.session.userId;
   socket.join('user:' + userId);
   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
     console.log("Rooms are left automatically on disconnect");
   }
});
```

On todo change:

```
io.to('user:' + userId).emit('TODO_CHANGE', change);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't think this scales vertically or horizontally, and could even fail on reconnects if the socketId changes... Still looking for that silver bullet I guess. For now, i've settled on socketcluster